# Symfony3 and login redirection

Tags: symfony, redirect

User tries open url
`http://example.com/page1?param=value`
default authentication redirects to 
`http://example.com/login`
after success login it redirects to 
`http://example.com/page1?param=value`
this one is ok.

Question is, how\where (what should i redefine and where) can I redirect to `http://example.com/login?param=value`. I need manual (my custom class) of redirection for login form (I want edit url).

Comment: Maybe this one helps? [How to Customize Redirect After Form Login](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate symfony, anyway solution found:

```
namespace some\lib;

class AuthenticationListener
{
    /**
     * Change some data in response before it fires up.
     *
     * @param FilterResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        if ($response instanceof RedirectResponse) {
            /** @var RedirectResponse $response */
            $parsedUrl = parse_url($response->getTargetUrl());

            if (!empty($parsedUrl['path'])) {
                $matchedRoute = $this->router->match($parsedUrl['path']);

                if (!empty($matchedRoute['_route']) && $matchedRoute['_route'] == 'login') {
                    $layout = $event->getRequest()->query->get('layout');

                    if ($layout) {
                        $response = $event->getResponse(); // response that should be fired up (redirect to url)

                        $responseUrl = $response->getTargetUrl();
                        $responseUrl .= is_int(strpos('?', $responseUrl)) // add layout to redirect url
                            ? '&layout=' . $layout
                            : '?layout=' . $layout;

                        $response->setTargetUrl($responseUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
// ... other code
```

Add to services.yml:

```
auth_listener:
    class: \some\lig\AuthenticationListener
    arguments: [] # inject yours
    tags:
        # some other definitions
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onResponse }
```

Only this way (afaik) we can add params from prev. url (target) to next url (redirect to login).

So we catch `RedirectResponse` and check it on kernel level.